# Best way to query view functions in solidity from react with ether.js?

Tags: solidity, react, ethers.js

This is to interact with my smart contract. My contract has a function like this e.g:

```
function getOfferById(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns (uint256) {
    require(_tokenId < MAX_B, "This tokenId does not exist");
    uint256 offer = bOffers[_tokenId];
    require(offer > 0, "There is no offer for this token");
    return offer;
}
```

Now what is to query this data on page load or whenever a new event comes and this data might have changed, I did it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function getOfferById() {
      if (myContracts) {
        const _getOfferById = myContracts.getOfferById;
        if (_getOfferById && id) {
          try {
            const _offer = await _getOfferById(id);
            setoffer(formatUnits(_offer, 'ether'));
          } catch (e) {
            setoffer(0);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    getOfferById();
  }, [myContracts, id, myEventOfferCreated, myEventOfferCanceled]);
```

But this way, I get a lot of console errors all the time from my metamask, because the require statement hits often.

What would be the best way to this?

Answer (score 1):

I always prefer to prevent require statements in `view` methods, unless it's really necessary. Because sometimes, backends like Metamask, due to some limitation, don't include the revert reason strings in the error, which causes user interfaces to have a hard time figuring out the cause of the error.

I'd instead suggest you to change your method to:

```
function getOfferById(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns (
  uint256 offer, bool tokenExists) {
    offer = bOffers[_tokenId];
    tokenExists = _tokenId < MAX_B;
}
```

So if `tokenExists` is false, you can display that in UI. Also if `offer === 0`, then you can display in UI that there is no offer.